# Binary operator overloading

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, templates, stl

I'm trying to create template Polynomical class with overloaded operator "+". I managed to make this to work with objects that are based on the same variable types (`int` + `int`), but now i'm stuck with adapting this to work with objects based on different types of variables (`float` + `int`).
I want to choose what kind of result i will get based on types of Polynomials i'm summing. Something like this:

```
float + int -> float;
float + double -> double;
int + int -> int;
unsigned int + int -> int;
```

And so on.

Right now i have following code:

```
    template <class ScalarType>
    class Polynomial {

    public:
      Polynomial<ScalarType> operator+ (const Polynomial<ScalarType>& other) const;

}

template <class ScalarType>
Polynomial<ScalarType> Polynomial<ScalarType>::operator+ (const Polynomial<ScalarType>& other) const {
  bool firstIsMore = this->size() > other.size();
  Polynomial<ScalarType> result(firstIsMore ? *this : other);

  typename std::vector<ScalarType>::iterator resultIt = result.nc_begin();
  typename std::vector<ScalarType>::const_iterator summIterBegin = (firstIsMore ? other.begin() : this->begin());
  typename std::vector<ScalarType>::const_iterator summIterEnd = (firstIsMore ? other.end() : this->end());

  while (summIterBegin != summIterEnd) {
    *resultIt += *summIterBegin;
    resultIt++;
    summIterBegin++;
  }

  return(result);
}
```

And this is my attempt to create neccesary functionality

```
  template <class OtherScalar>
  Polynomial<ScalarType> operator+ (const Polynomial<OtherScalar>& other) const;


template <class ScalarType>
class Polynomial {

public:

  template <class OtherScalar>
  Polynomial<ScalarType> operator+ (const Polynomial<OtherScalar>& other) const;

}

template <class ScalarType>
template <class OtherScalar>
Polynomial<ScalarType> Polynomial<ScalarType>::operator+ (const Polynomial<OtherScalar>& other) const {

  std::vector<ScalarType> summResult = this->getCoefficients();
  std::vector<OtherScalar> toSumm = other.getCoefficients();

  std::transform(summResult.begin(),
                 summResult.end(),
                 toSumm.begin(),
                 summResult.begin(),
                 [](const ScalarType& first, const OtherScalar& second){return (first + second);});

  if (summResult.size() < toSumm.size()) {
    summResult.insert(summResult.end(), toSumm.begin() + (toSumm.size() - summResult.size()), toSumm.end());
  }

  return(Polynomial(summResult));
}
```

But if i use this i will get Polynominal based on first one's type in binary expression, and that not what i need.

Finalizing question: Is it possible to create binary operator that returns result based on operand's types but without taking their order in account.
(Since it works with simple numberical types it is possible, but i have no idea how to make this work)

I'm storing coefficient of polynominal in `std::vector<ScalarType>`
[Here](https://pastebin.com/MaYuE68x) is full class code

Comment: Didn't read the whole post, but you may find [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `decltype()` could help you.

Something like

```
template <class OtherScalar>
Polynomial<decltype(ScalarType()+OtherScalar())> operator+
   (const Polynomial<OtherScalar>& other) const;
```

ps: caution: not tested